# the existence of R-regular and M-regular element over Noetherian local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> $(R,\mathfrak m,k)$ is a Noetherian local ring, and $M≠0$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $\operatorname{depth}R≧1$ and $\operatorname{depth}M≧1$. Then $\mathfrak m$ contains an element which is both $R$-regular and $M$-regular.

I tried to solve this by a lemma (see below) but couldn't.

> **Lemma:** Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M, N$ finite $R$-modules, and $I=\operatorname{Ann}(N)$. Then $\operatorname{Hom}(M, N)=0$ implies that $I$ contains an $M$-regular element.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\newcommand{\zdv}{\operatorname{Zdv}}\zdv(M)$ denote the set of all zerodivisors on $M$. Suppose that $\mathfrak m\subset \zdv(R)\cup \zdv(M).$ Since $$\zdv(M)=\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in{\rm Ass}(M)}\mathfrak p,$$
we see that $\mathfrak m$ is contained in a union of prime ideals. Then, by prime avoidance, we obtain that $\mathfrak m\subset \zdv(R)$ or $\mathfrak m\subset \zdv(M)$, a contradiction to the hypothesis. Thus $\mathfrak m\not\subset \zdv(R)\cup \zdv(M)$. This means that $\mathfrak m$ contains an element which is both $R$-regular and $M$-regular.